# Appending multiple JSON from API into singular JSON file

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to obtain JSON data on individual game matches from an API and compile it. This will give me a large amount of data to practice analysis and coding with. However, my initial approach takes individual JSON responses and turns them into a list that cannot be read.

e.g.

```
{
    "gameCreation": 4526587452121,
    "gameDuration": 1456,
    "gameId": 1459885348,
}
...
{
    "gameCreation": 1594575625478,
    "gameDuration": 2145,
    "gameId": 1458898753,
}
```

Predictably, python doesn't like this. Instead, it needs to be told that these are matches like so...

```
{
    "matches": [
        {
        "gameCreation": 4526587452121,
        "gameDuration": 1456,
        "gameId": 1459885348,
        }
        ...
        {
        "gameCreation": 1594575625478,
        "gameDuration": 2145,
        "gameId": 1458898753,
        }
    ]
}
```

My orignal code looked as follows:

```
#I use a for-loop and game IDs to retrive 
#match data from the API
for game_id in game_ids:

    #Obtain the data from API
    full_match_data = watcher.match.by_id(my_region, game_id)
    #Open up the file I want to store all the matches in
    file_handle = open(all_matches_index, "a")
    #write the matches in
    file_handle.write(json.dumps(full_match_data, sort_keys=True, indent = 4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

I thought by changing the last line to include 'matches' I would solve this problem.

```
file_handle.write(json.dumps["matches"{(full_match_data, sort_keys=True, indent = 4, separators=(',', ': '))}])
```

But this doesn't work and returns.

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Evidently, I'm trying to find something called 'matches' rather than creating it and using it as the name of my match list. Where am I going wrong?

Am I just making my life difficult by not making the initial file contain:

```
{
        "matches": [
        ]
}
```

and then using something like...

```
file_handle.matches.write(json.dumps(full_match_data, sort_keys=True, indent = 4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Close but no cigar, when writing or appending the file use...

```
file_handle.write(json.dumps({"matches" : [full_match_data]}, sort_keys=True, indent = 4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```